# Writing the comparator for the PriorityBlockingQueue

Tags: java, comparator

My PriorityBlockingQueue has got Message objects which have group ID. Based on the Group ID, the elements in the queue are to be sorted. This messages from the queue are taken and simultaneously new messages are added. If the group ID has already been been processed, the messages of that group ID has to be sent first.

I have written a comparator which does that however, the messages with Group IDs not been processed, are not getting ordered properly.

Here is my comparator

```
List<Integer> grpProcessed = Gateway.getGrpAlreadyProcessed();

    if (grpProcessed.contains(arg0.getGroupID()) && grpProcessed.contains(arg1.getGroupID())) {
        return 1;
    } else if (grpProcessed.contains(arg0.getGroupID())) {
        return -1;
    }       
    return 1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you returning 1 by default?

Comment: by returning 1, the arg0 gets added below arg1, isn't it?

Comment: Also, the method return int, so there has to be default

Comment: Your comparator violates transitivity property: if both `arg0` and `arg1` are already processed, it returns 1 when comparing them, which means that `arg1 > arg0` and at the same time `arg0 > arg1` if arguments were given in another order

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your order more properly. How will two messages be compared to each other when both are (not) processed? (You should return 0 only [if the two objects equal each other](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-)). The [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface also defines more requirements (results need to be transitive, ...). You could start with this code (untested of course):

```
// Check if arg0 is processed
if (grpProcessed.contains(arg0.getGroupID())) {
    if (grpProcessed.contains(arg1.getGroupID())) {
        // Both arg0 and arg1 are processed
        return Objects.equals(arg0, arg1) ? 0 : Integer.compare(System.identityHashCode(arg0), System.identityHashCode(arg1));
    }
    // Only arg0 is processed
    return 1;
}
// Check if arg1 is processed
if (grpProcessed.contains(arg1.getGroupID())) {
    // Only arg1 is processed
    return -1;
}
// Neither arg0 nor arg1 are processed
return Objects.equals(arg0, arg1) ? 0 : Integer.compare(System.identityHashCode(arg0), System.identityHashCode(arg1));
```

Comment: @Madz Depends on what you expect, right? It probably is the `Integer.compare(System.identityHashCode(...), ...)`: This puts a random, but constant and natural order on the elements. You need to define your own order (I read FCFS). Replace the `Integer.compare(System.identityHashCode(...), ...)` with `arg1.getGroupID() - arg0.getGroupID()` if the group IDs are assigned in order. If not, add a timestamp to the messages and use this for replacement: `arg1.getCreationTime() - arg0.getCreationTime()`.

Comment: The GroupIDs are not created in order, Timestamp is very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: just add constant big number to items that were unprocessed already, so id of any processed item will be greater than id of any unprocessed:

```
int bigId = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2;
int id0 = grpProcessed.contains(arg0.getGroupID()) ? arg0.getGroupID() : (arg0.getGroupID() + bigId);
int id1 = grpProcessed.contains(arg1.getGroupID()) ? arg1.getGroupID() : (arg1.getGroupID() + bigId); 
return id0 - id1;
```

If you use full-range `int` for ID, make comparison using `long`.

If you need to divide elements into 2 groups keeping their order, just use:

```
return (grpProcessed.contains(arg0.getGroupID()) ? 0 : 1) - (grpProcessed.contains(arg1.getGroupID()) ? 0 : 1);
```

Comment: this solution sorts the rest of the unprocessed messages in decreasing order. I want to retain the FCFS for those

Comment: @Madz then just assign `0` or another small number as substitute `id0` and `id1` to unprocessed messages. Java's sort is stable (i.e. keeps order of same value elements).

Comment: This works, but couple of times it still doesn't do FCFS. For 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1, 3 Output is: 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2, 2. Should have been: 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 0

Comment: Timsort is stable. So if you your input is `[1, 2*, 1*, 3, 2, 3*]` (* means processed), after `Collections.sort()` it will be `[2*, 1*, 3*, 1, 3, 2]`, because in terms of comparator I provided in second snippet, elements are equally valued (= 0 or 1) if they are both processed or unprocessed.

Comment: Yes, I better do a time sort for the rest of messages not processed. Thanks for your help.